# Phalcon documentation: installation/FreeBSD

Tags: installation, phalcon, freebsd

I'm trying to install phalcon by it's documentation! and in this step i have an error:

> installation/FreeBSD
>
> Command: pkg_add -r phalcon

Error:

> 'pkg_add' is not recognized as an internal or external command...

What is the problem? Please guide me...

Comment: Sounds like the comand `pkg_add` not exist's. Is all the essential utilities installed?

Comment: What is the essential utilities?! I do all the previous steps according to documentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to edit:

```
vi Edit /root/.cshrc
```

adding the follow line:

```
setenv PACKAGESITE "ftp://ftp.FreeBSD.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/<architecture>/packages-current/Latest/"
```

where `<architeture>` is something like `amd64` or `i386`

Then log out and back in, and try again to run `pkg_add -r phalcon`

Comment: Use `setenv PACKAGESITE "ftp://ftp.FreeBSD.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-current/Latest/"` for amd64 and `setenv PACKAGESITE "ftp://ftp.FreeBSD.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/i386/packages-current/Latest/"` for i386

Comment: If you found that the provided answer was also nice, could you give a +1 too ;)

Comment: Sorry, I can't! because my reputation is not enough and i can't vote! but i accept your answer ---> +15 ;)